# How to solve permutation group equations?(discrete mathematics,group theory)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

$\pi^2=(1\ 2\  3\  4\  5),\pi \in S_{5} \\
 \\
\pi^2=(1\ 2\  3\  4\  5\ 6),\pi \in S_{10} $

These are two different equations.Where $\pi$ is the cycle of the permutation, I know that the set $S_{5}$ has $5!$ elements and $\in S_{10}$ has $10!$ elements.

Comment: You are looking for a permutation $\pi$ such that $\pi^2=(1 2 3 4 5)$. The obvious thing to try is a power of $(1 2 3 4 5)$.

Comment: You should clarify your Question and explain what you've tried.  I think you are asking about two problems, one where we want a "square root" of the cycle $(1\;2\;3\;4\;5)$ in $S_5$, and a similar exercise about a cycle of length six in $S_{10}$.

Comment: this is the exact text of the exercise: Solve the following permutation equations. Give the answer as a "product" of disjoint cycles.

Comment: Hint : use the equations to find the possible orders of $\pi$ then find the possible cycle decompositions of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints to put you on track.

In the first case $\pi^{10}=(1)$ so the order of $\pi$ divides $10$.

If $\pi=\pi_1\circ\cdots\circ\pi_n$ where the $\pi_i$ are disjoint cykels then the order of $\pi$ equals $\text{lcm}(l_1,\cdots,l_n)$ where $l_i$ is the length of cykel $\pi_i$.

Comment: I read many articels about these topics but it's not obvious how to solve the equations.